# ubuntu desktop or server as dedicated server

Tags: webserver

I am considering to host my website with Ubuntu as a dedicated server. But what variant of Ubuntu should I choose, Ubuntu desktop or Ubuntu Server edition? Please provide a reason of choosing either.

**Update**

Note: The dedicated server will host my clients websites(around 100s) and also it need to work as web server/database server/ftp server and other application servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use desktop at home. it allows me to have a remote logon pc, home theater pc, and a webserver all in one.

in a business environment, server is better. having worked with both, you have to evaluate how you will use it. It is important for me to have that remote desktop and the webserver. your circumstances are likely different.

Comment: Please check I have updated the question with a note

Comment: Definitely straight server if that's the work your doing. grab a coke and a laptop, and sit down and grind on using the terminal interface. desktop idols using about 300MB of RAM, server idols at 120MB. plus SQL and apps just seem to run better on the server, in my experience.